# Why does PowerBI show "This table is empty" when getting data from a Microsoft Access Database?

Tags: powerbi, ms-access-2013

I have records stored in 2 tables in a Microsoft Access Database that I would like to load into powerBI.

When i try to import the data in PowerBI, I select **Get Data -> Access database -> mydatabase** and the file loads. PowerBI recognizes my tables and column names, however it says that both tables are empty.

The database and dashboard are both local on my machine.

Any idea how to solve this? There are over a thousand rows of data in my database.

Comment: HI, and welcome :) Could you share the output you are seeing, be editing your Question to include this? This may help others to find a solution to you problem.

Answer (score 0):

is your Office/Access 32 bit or 64? ...  PowerBI use to only connect to 64 bit Access although would work to 32 bit Excel.  my info is dated so double check this.

also do a quick export of the tables to excel and then see if that connect works...just as a sanity check